# What are the top introductory texts on the Justinian Codex?

Tags: history

I'm a non-lawyer interested in reading an introduction to the Justinian Codex such as would be assigned to orient students in a law school program.

What are the usual suspects here?

Thanks,

Comment: as asked, extremely broad and opinion based still. "Top" implies ranking the text, and what is an introduction is highly opinion based.

Comment: A perfectly proper question. Legal texts are regularly (and easily) ranked using objective criteria.

Comment: after digging out old study material, I point to... the Corpus Iuris Civilis itself: it contained its own study book for then-aspiring lawyers! Brush up your Latin Christos.

Comment: @Christos In wich language the text should be? And "intruductory" means how long?

Comment: I would prefer a language of English or French; I can handle gobbets of Latin or Greek but would prefer not to have long stretches. And I was envisioning book length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### When?

There are basically several times to look at when you want to look at the text, and then in what language. The **Codex Iustinianus** itself is part of the **Corpus iuris civilis** and contained only laws given by the previous emperors, while other older laws were in the *Digesta/Pandecta* and the *Novellae* contained any new imperial laws after 534. The whole CICiv, was given an introductory text right from inception:

When it was compiled, back around 528, one of the books of the CICiv was the **Institutiones Iustiniani**, which was the prescribed legal education basis - the study book for the aspiring lawyers of his time. It contained how to practice law and cases that were to be discussed. On this basis, a *glossa marginalis* commentary has survived in Turin, which was made from a copy of the *Institutiones*. The commentary is dated to be contemporary to the CICiv and was made by adding comments around the real text, making researchers believe this was a work by a teacher, so he could answer or explain parts of the text, or reference earlier parts of the book easier.

Around the 7th century, the *Pandekta/Digesta* were pretty much forgotten in big parts.

In the middle ages, it took about till late 1000s, early 1100s, to re-compile the CICiv, when Irnerius of Bologna did manage to collect a sizeable portion of it by rediscovering the *Littera Florentina* and added to this collection by referencing earlier *glossae*. The *Florentina* alone is more than 900 pages long, and his **littera vulgata/bologniensis** ([a german edition's Bibliography](http://d-nb.info/780340973) [an Italian edition's bibliography](https://www.europeana.eu/en/item/2023810/ms_internetCulturale_php_id_oai_3Awww_internetculturale_sbn_it_2FTeca_3A20_3ANT0000_3ASISMEL_RMS0099481_b)), a new commentary on the re-compiled laws, including large parts of the *Digesta*. This book became the new introduction and teaching text about the CICiv and leading teaching bok for all lawyers in Europe at that time. This text is, what defined the *roman tradition of law*

In the 19th century, legal scholars that studied a lot of the CICiv and argued along those lines - a style predominantly Existant in Germany - were known as Pandectists. One of the more central books of them was the *[Lehrbuch der Pandeketen](http://dlib-pr.mpier.mpg.de/m/kleioc/0010/exec/books/%2296050%22)* by Karl Ludwig Arndts von Arnesberg (Stuttgart 1877). The praxis that developed in these circles greatly did influence the style of how the German *Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch* BGB was organized and written, and this systematic was exported.

Later, books such as Paul Koschaker: *Europa und das römische Recht* (4th edition Munich 1966) did recept the whole roman legal body, giving the CiCiv a very thorough look, and how it influenced the modern *Code Civil* and *Germanic tradition of law*, while Franz Wieacker: *Privatrechtsgeschichte der Neuzeit unter besonderer Berücksichtigung der deutschen Entwicklung* (2nd Edition, Göttingen 1967) did look at the Pandectists and how they were influenced by the CICiv.

As more scholarly works I want to point to three that were referenced in the notes of the page when my ancient history Professor mentioned Roman Law being "verklauselt, kompliziert und voller sonderfälle" (~complicated and with many exceptions) in passing.

- [*A Short History of Roman Law* by Olga Tellegen-Couperus (1993)](https://books.google.de/books?id=R9-kvagJ_7sC) does spare the last 8 pages on the CiCiv.
- The more thorough [Herbert Felix Jolowicz; Barry Nicholas: *Historical Introduction to the Study of Roman Law* (Cambridge 1967)](https://books.google.de/books?id=Nwg9AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) does spare the last chapters on the CICiv.
- [Adolf Berger, Adolf: *Encyclopedic Dictionary of Roman Law* (The American Journal of Philology 1953)](https://books.google.com/books?id=oR0LAAAAIAAJ) is taken still one of the main shorthands and (sometimes outdated) bibliographies under historians.

Large parts of the Latin CICiv (as #12) can be accessed in "[the Roman Law Library](https://droitromain.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/)" by the Grenoble University, together with edition scans.